# What does vector<int> a(b) mean, in c++?

Tags: c++, vector

Recently, I've started learning vector. I can't understand a syntax in vector. I googled it but couldn't find any satisfied answer.

```
std::vector<int> path;  
std::vector<int> newpath(path);
```

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: it most likely `Type variable_name(constructor_parameters)`

Comment: Can you add the type of `path` to the question?

Comment: @lubgr path is assigned as vector<int> path

Comment: `vector<int>` declares a `vector` which can contain `int` values. For detailed information search for C++ *templates*.

Comment: `newpath` is a strange name for `vector<int>`.

Comment: Perhaps a [`std::vector` constructor reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) might help?

Comment: More specifically: Have you ever heard of *copy-constructors*? If not then it's time [to get some books to read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282), from the start.

Comment: @Jarod42 If `path` is to be copied to then be modified to create a new path, `newpath` is a sensible name to me.

Comment: @JimmyB: even `path` is a strange name, `std::vector<EDirection> path;` or `std::vector<int> numbers;` seems more appropriate.

Comment: @Ron it's just a syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second line copy-constructs a new `std::vector<int>` instance from `path`. Thereafter both vectors store identical data.

Comment: Is _identical_ a reserved terminology for objects having equal salient non-salient objects? I meant value-equality in terms of `operator ==`, where `capacity()` and `data()` doesn't come into play. But I'm happy to adjust the wording if `identical` actually means something different.

Comment: I think the word you're after is *equivalent*, i.e. compare equal with `operator==`.

Comment: @Walter Thanks for the fix! I don't know whether _equivalent_ is the right word either, though. Equality is a form of equivalence, but not the only one. I guess _equality_ is the best term here.